# How to make an element sticky to the virtual keyboard on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, mobile-safari, virtual-keyboard

consider the usecase of a rich-text-editor. The toolbar of that editor should be sticky to the keyboard when the editor is focused to access the icons of the toolbar.

I tried with the obvious soln -

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

but that din't help on ios safari as the page behaviour is panning on virtual keyboard appearance. Say, the toolbar is getting hidden behind the keyboard.

Any help is highly appreciated, Thank you.